# Really basic Sudoku-like programme

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a procedure (symmetric(p)) that takes as an input a list which has to be square shaped like a Sudoku game, and whose components are also lists, and outputs the value true or false if the "square" is symmetric or not.

The square is symmetric if the first row is equivalent to the first column, the second row is equivalent to the second column and so on.  Now, I've written the code but it doesn't work. Its output is always True. Here is a paste of the code:

```
def column_building(list, position):
  column = []
  for i in list:
    column.append(i[position])
  return column

a = [[1, 2, 3],
     [2, 3, 4],
     [3, 4, 1]]

b = [["cat", "dog", "fish"],
     ["dog", "dog", "dog"],
     ["fish","fish","cat"]]

def symmetric(p):
  counter = 0
  for e in p:
    if e == column_building(p, counter):
      counter = counter + 1
      return True
    else:
      return False
      break

print symmetric(b)
```

In the code, the first procedures tell which is the column in a determined position. `a` and `b` are lists that I created to use as examples. And, as I said, it outputs always True, but if I use `b`, when `e` is the second element of the list, it is not equal to the column built with the second position (`[dog, dog, fish]`).

Answer (score 2):

Python magic!

```
def symmetric(p):
    return list(map(list, zip(*p))) == p
```

Here, `zip(*p)` just transposes the given list of lists. In fact, you need to check whether `transpose(p) == p`.

If you're using Python 2.7, you can remove the outer call to `list`.

Comment: Yes, this is the best answer +1. It would simply be list(zip(*b)) if it was a list with tuples, so this could be an alternative. **list(zip(*b)) == list(map(tuple,b))**

Comment: Thanks for the help! however, since i am a real beginner in this thing of python magic (haha) i haven't learn those functions, so i have to sort the activity out without them.

Answer (score 0):

To fix (rather than replace) your code, I'd suggest:

```
def symmetric(p):
    counter = 0

    for e in p:
        if e != column_building(p, counter):
            return False
        counter += 1

    return True
```

You were returning `True` and `False` at the wrong time as the problem is simpler than you're making it.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. Now, I didn't learn such function as enumerate yet, so there must be a way to make this code work without it, i think. Apart from that, would you tell me whats wrong with my original code? i mean, i know it's wrong because it does not work, but i don't really see why, what i wrote or tried to wrote is basically: if the first row is equal to the first column, add one to the counter, return True, and go to the next element(list) in p (list), if not, return False and end the loop.

Comment: @PedroLopez, I've updated my answer to use your original counter logic instead of `enumerate()` which basically does the same thing.  Your original code was wrong because you returned `True` from within the loop.  It's OK to return `False` during the loop, if *any* test fails, but you can't know if it's `True` until the loop completes and *all* tests have succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy version:

```
import numpy as np

b = [["cat", "dog", "fish"],
["dog", "dog", "dog"],
["fish","fish","cat"]]

np.all(np.array(b) == np.array(b).T) # all True = True, else False
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that you need to check whether `transpose(p) == p`

Comment: Where do you find that `transpose` function?

Comment: import numpy as np and: np.array(b) == np.array(b).T